How to connect Rstudio to remove AWS RDS database through TCP/IP SSH tunnel
I'm trying to connect to a remote AWS MySQL database that is over TCP/IP SSH.
I can successfully connect using the same credentials in both Sequel Pro and MySQL Workbench, but I can't get the R script to play ball.
there is no place in to pass SSH info such as
`# SSH gateway information
  `ssh_server <- ""`
  `ssh_user <- ""`
  `ssh_key <- "c:/01_todo/westKey.pem"``

I think I'm suppose to maybe establish an SSH connection in R Studio terminal before connecting.  but no idea how..
tried to connect but unable to pass the SSH credentials.
